# apache web server configuration problem

Tags: apache2

i want to have apache server to serve only 
/var/www/  directory
now it serves all my files on system from directory 
"/"
i tried to edit httpd.conf placed in /etc/apache2 and placed the folllowing content in it(intially it was empty)

```
<Directory />
   Options None
   AllowOverride None
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www"

<Directory "/var/www">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

then saved it,restarted apache server
put the location /var/www in the web browser address bar,still it shows the higher level directories too
then i edited the file Default,Default-ssl in the sites-available folder 
repeated the same process

still apache serves all files on my system

---

2.when i try to use the following command

```
gedit httpd.conf
```

I get the error

```
gedit:2696): EggSMClient-WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported

GConf Error: Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it look like this:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

Do you see a site listed named "000-default" or similar?
if it is not listed, I would type:

```
sudo a2ensite default
```

Also, cat your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file.

You should have something similar to below. I **personally** added a DocumentRoot /var/www a line above my VirtualHost line.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```